# Meteor JS : How to get latest set of data based on the date?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a requirement where my db has say some set of records with same timestamp (latest) and i want to get all of them at once, i don't want to get any other data which doesn't belong to that criteria, problem is i will not know the timestamp because it stored in db from outside world.

How do i get only the latest set of data in meteor ? i cant do findOne, as it will bring only 1 latest record, which is wrong in my case.

```
Meteor.publish("collection1", function() {
  return Collection1.find({}, {sort:{dateTime: -1}});
});
```

I tried to do above code but it gets all the record and i think it just sort by desc.

Comment: `{sort:{dateTime: -1}, limit: 10}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **[`findOne()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/findone)** method to get the latest `dateTime` value that you can then use as the **[`find()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find)** query:

```
// on the server
Meteor.publish("collection1", function() {
    var latest = Collection1.findOne({}, {"sort":{"dateTime": -1}}).dateTime;
    return Collection1.find({"dateTime": latest});
});

// on the client
Meteor.subscribe("collection1");
Collection1.find().fetch();
```

The above approach makes your Meteor app scalable client-side as the client only subscribes to the data that you only need. This is made possible because the return statement inside the **[`Meteor.publish`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish)** function can only return documents that have the latest `dateTime` value. This way, you'll avoid overloading the browser's memory no matter how big your server-side database is.

Comment: in the client (subscribe) i should return Collection1.find({}) ?? or same thing i need what you have mentioned ?

Comment: @SharathBangera I've added some explanation to the answer on how you can subscribe on client-side.

Comment: @chridam How does this work, when i use limit, like fetching the latest 50 records?